# Why would you use jQuery $(window).ready() and how is it different from $(window).load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have come across some code using `$(window).ready()` that does dome UI resizing and positioning on HTML elements. I wondering why it is used? Is there an advantage to using it this way?

Are there any advantages over `$(document).ready()?`

Comment: Thanks for answers, a quick search on google did not find references to window.ready, and have never really used it like I saw today. Thought I might be missing a trick!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The advantage of `ready` over the `load` event is that it fires as soon as the DOM is ready, without waiting for the distance resources (mainly the images) to be loaded. Usually you just want to be sure the elements are present, so that you can bind to them, but you don't need the distance resources to be loaded.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

> In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has
>   been fully constructed

`$(window).ready()` and `$(document).ready()` are equivalent.

From [the source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) :

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Add the callback
    jQuery.ready.promise().done( fn );

    return this;
},
```

You see that the argument isn't even used, it's just returned so that you can chain if you want. You could have done this :

```
$({}).ready(function(){
    ...
});
```

But you shouldn't worry and should use the shortcut :

```
$(function(){
    // your code which needs the DOM here
});
```

Comment: @ArunKillu I think that's exactly what he said.- `The advantage of window.ready is that it fires as soon as the DOM is ready, without waiting for the distance resources (mainly the images) to be loaded`

Comment: never heard of `$(window).ready`. They are equivalent because the argument is ignored completely. The jQuery docs suggest `$(document).ready()` and `$()` as equally good.

Comment: sorry i just misinterpreted sorry and +1

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the jQuery 1.9.0 source code, and it doesn't look like the `.ready()` method uses at the object it was applied to; it has `document` hard-coded throughout it. So all `$(anything).ready(...)` calls are equivalent.

Download the source code and see the definition of `jquery.ready.promise`, this is where most of the work of `$(...).ready()` is done.

The documentation makes it clear that `$(window).ready()` doesn't have a defined meaning:

> The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

Currently the object is ignored, the above allows them to change this behavior in the future, since it shouldn't impact any correctly-written code.